# Top alignment of cell with figures

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, includegraphics

I would like to align the content of each cell (in the first column) to the top. The approaches presented here do not apply. Maybe it has something to do with the tabular environment?

```
\begin{figure}[ht!] 
\begin{center}          
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \textbf{(a)} & \begin{tabular}[t]{l} \includegraphics[width=16pc]{example-image1.jpeg} \end{tabular}&\hspace*{-4mm}
        \textbf{(b)} & \begin{tabular}[t]{l} \includegraphics[width=16pc]{example-image2.jpeg} \end{tabular}\\
        \textbf{(c)} & \begin{tabular}[t]{l} \includegraphics[width=16pc]{example-image3.jpeg} \end{tabular}&\hspace*{-4mm}
        \textbf{(d)} & \begin{tabular}[t]{l} \includegraphics[width=16pc]{example-image4.jpeg} \end{tabular}\\
    \end{tabular}   
\end{center}    
\caption{COSMIC-2.} 
\label{fig:sec21}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: why the nested  tabular? (just  use valign=t on includegraphics from adjustbox package)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you very much. It worked

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

**Edit:**
Ups, first column should be on the top of cells, not in the middle. Sorry for confusion ...

[image]

But simplified and completed your code fragment, MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}          % it loads graphicx too

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\adjustboxset{width=16pc,
              margin=1pt, valign=t  % <---
              }
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\bfseries}c cc @{}}
 (a) & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} \\ 
 (b) & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} \\
 (c) & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} \\ 
 (d) & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Test}
    \label{test}      
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

following @David Carlisle suggestion, I got an answer

```
\begin{figure}[ht!] 
\begin{center}          
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \textbf{(a)}\includegraphics[width=18pc, keepaspectratio=true, valign=t, trim=230 50 100 50, clip]{fig1.jpeg}&\hspace*{-4mm}
        \textbf{(b)}\includegraphics[width=18pc, keepaspectratio=true, valign=t, trim=230 50 100 50, clip]{fig2.jpeg}\\
        \textbf{(c)}\includegraphics[width=18pc, keepaspectratio=true, valign=t, trim=230 50 100 50, clip]{fig3.jpeg}&\hspace*{-4mm}
        \textbf{(d)}\includegraphics[width=18pc, keepaspectratio=true, valign=t, trim=230 50 160 50, clip]{fig4.jpeg}\\
    \end{tabular}   
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks

Comment: Glad your issue was resolved, is there any chance you could extend your code into a small self-contained example that people can compile please? Helps with future readers

Comment: Don't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` inside `figure`, but declare `\centering`. You should also add the `p` option: `\begin{figure}[!htp]`.

Comment: @JamesT, you put my code into Zarko's example above.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of `valign=t` is good, but you can improve a lot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\textbf{(a)} &
  \includegraphics[width=18pc, trim=0 100 0 0, clip, valign=t]{example-image} \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(b)} & 
  \includegraphics[width=18pc, trim=0 100 0 0, clip, valign=t]{example-image} \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(c)} &
  \includegraphics[width=18pc, trim=0 100 0 0, clip, valign=t]{example-image} \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{(d)} &
  \includegraphics[width=18pc, trim=0 100 0 0, clip, valign=t]{example-image} \\
\end{tabular}   

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note `\centering` instead of the `center` environment and the two-column tabular with no padding on either side (obtained with `@{}`). Also `p` should be added to the options to `figure` (and a `\caption` is essentially mandatory).

I used different values for the trimming, as I can't know about your images. There's no need to add `keepaspectratio=true`, since you only specify the width.

[image]